# How to send json string to phil sturgeon's Rest Controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-post, codeigniter-restserver

This question may be stupid. I want to know if its possible to send a string like {"type":"kissme", "who":"john bennet"} to rest controller as a post request.

I know that post data has to be sent as somekey=somevalue&otherkey=othervalue as body of the request. While receiving we refer to the key to get the data. But how can we send any string without assigning to a key like json data ? If it is possible to send, how to receive ?

Thank you,
Abbiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used file_get_contents('php://input'); while reading in controller. i use the content-type header as application/x-www-form-urlencoded while posting the data

Answer (score 0):

**REST implementation for CodeIgniter**

> You can use any of the following formats too simply by appending
>   /format/json to the end of your URL or passing the correct MIME-type:
>
> 1. xml
> 2. json
> 3. serialize
> 4. php (raw output that can be used in eval)
> 5. html
> 6. csv

**Source:** http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/06/REST-implementation-for-CodeIgniter